# productId is ignored and returned as null when validating Android In App Product via purchases.products.get

Tags: php, android, google-play, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to validate a Google Play/Android In App Product consumed purchase server-side using PHP. I get a response back with a valid receipt, but there are two confusing issues:

1. The `productId` is always `null`
2. If I change the the `$productId` in the sample below to an invalid ID, it will return the exact same response. This seems to be the case for literally any string.

Here is my sample code:

```php
$purchaseToken = 'TEST purchaseToken FROM ANDROID APP';
$appId = 'com.example.myapp';
$productId = 'com.example.myapp.iap1';

$googleClient = new \Google_Client();
$googleClient->setScopes([\Google_Service_AndroidPublisher::ANDROIDPUBLISHER]);
$googleClient->setApplicationName($appId);
$googleClient->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/gp-service.json');
$googleAndroidPublisher = new \Google_Service_AndroidPublisher($googleClient);
$purchase = $googleAndroidPublisher->purchases_products->get($appId, $productId, $purchaseToken);
```

If I dump out `$purchase`, I get:

```
=> Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_ProductPurchase {
     +acknowledgementState: 1,
     +consumptionState: 1,
     +developerPayload: "",
     +kind: "androidpublisher#productPurchase",
     +obfuscatedExternalAccountId: null,
     +obfuscatedExternalProfileId: null,
     +orderId: "GPA.XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX",
     +productId: null,
     +purchaseState: 0,
     +purchaseTimeMillis: "1602771022178",
     +purchaseToken: null,
     +purchaseType: 0,
     +quantity: null,
     +regionCode: "US",
   }
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? It doesn't seem to be validating the `productId` on its end nor does it provide me the data I would need to validate it on my end, meaning I have no way of validating this IAP right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing Deusald's response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64450209/1515620) and starting to type up a response to the Google Issues ticket complaining about it, I had an epiphany: Google is just validating that the transaction is valid for your account and expects you to validate the receipt data server-side. They include a base64 encoded RSA SHA1 signature in the receipt data and the original data they used to create that signature, so they give you everything you need to accomplish this.

The below snippet accomplishes that verification for PHP, but it should be easily portable to other languages:

```php
<?php

// our app's bundle id
$appId = 'com.example.myapp';

// the location of a Service Account JSON file for a Service account that has access to the "Financial Data" permissions in the Play Console
$serviceAccountJson = __DIR__ . '/gp-service.json';

// this is the raw receipt data received on the device from Google Play; this example is obfuscated and only shows the keys for sensitive fields
$googlePlayReceipt = '{"productId": "com.example.myapp.iap1","transactionDate": 1602714720893,"transactionReceipt": "","purchaseToken": "","transactionId": "","dataAndroid": "","signatureAndroid": "","isAcknowledgedAndroid": false,"autoRenewingAndroid": false,"purchaseStateAndroid": 1}';
// decode the json to an array we can use
$decodedGooglePlayReceipt = json_decode($googlePlayReceipt, true);

// the data that was signed for verification purposes
$data = $decodedGooglePlayReceipt['transactionReceipt'];
// the signature that was used to sign the $data
$signature = $decodedGooglePlayReceipt['signatureAndroid'];

// The "Base64-encoded RSA public key" for your app, taken from the Google Play Console
// In the Classic Console: Your App -> Development Tools -> Services & APIs -> Licensing & in-app billing
// In the New Console: Your App -> Monetize -> Monetization Setup -> Licensing
$base64EncodedPublicKeyFromGoogle  = '################';

// Convert the key into the normal public key format
// Just need to split the base64 key into 64 character long lines and add the usual prefix/suffix
$openSslFriendlyKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" . chunk_split($base64EncodedPublicKeyFromGoogle, 64, "\n") .  "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
// Convert the key to the openssl key ID that openssl_verify() expects
// I'm unsure if this step would be necessary on all platforms
$publicKeyId = openssl_get_publickey($openSslFriendlyKey);

// Use openssl_verify() to verify the $signature (which has to be base64 decoded!) against the $data using the public key we have
$result = openssl_verify($data, base64_decode($signature), $publicKeyId, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
if ($result === 1) {
    // receipt data is valid. now let's grab the productId and purchaseToken
    $decodedData = json_decode($data, true);
    $purchasedProductId = decodedData['productId'];
    $purchaseToken = decodedData['purchaseToken'];

    // now we'll verify that the receipt is valid for our account
    try {
        $googleClient = new \Google_Client();
        $googleClient->setScopes([\Google_Service_AndroidPublisher::ANDROIDPUBLISHER]);
        $googleClient->setApplicationName($appId);
        $googleClient->setAuthConfig($serviceAccountJson);
        $googleAndroidPublisher = new \Google_Service_AndroidPublisher($googleClient);
        $purchase = $googleAndroidPublisher->purchases_products->get($appId, $purchasedProductId, $purchaseToken);
    } catch (Throwable $exception) {
        // this means the receipt data is unable to be validated by Google
        throw new Exception('Invalid receipt');
    }
} elseif ($result === 0) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid receipt');
} else {
    throw new Exception(openssl_error_string());
}
```

Comment: Hey @Josh ! This didn't run for me, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169870112

I've found on google issue tracker that ignoring productId is an intended behaviour. I've wrote post asking if the null that we receive in response is also an intended behaviour. I hope not because as you wrote if productId will be always null we have no way of fully validating IAP right now.

Comment: I figured out how Google was expecting us to handle this and posted a full PHP-based snippet in my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64467308/1515620

Answer (score 0):

$purchaseToken was undefined in Josh's answer.

```
<?php
$appId = "com.example.myapp";
$serviceAccountJson = __DIR__ . "/gp-service.json";

// this is the raw receipt data received on the device from Google Play; this example is obfuscated and only shows the keys for sensitive fields
$googlePlayReceipt =
    '{"productId": "com.example.myapp.iap1","transactionDate": 1602714720893,"transactionReceipt": "","purchaseToken": "","transactionId": "","dataAndroid": "","signatureAndroid": "","isAcknowledgedAndroid": false,"autoRenewingAndroid": false,"purchaseStateAndroid": 1}';
// decode the json to an array we can use
$decodedGooglePlayReceipt = json_decode($googlePlayReceipt, true);

// the data that was signed for verification purposes
$data = $decodedGooglePlayReceipt["transactionReceipt"];
// the signature that was used to sign the $data
$signature = $decodedGooglePlayReceipt["signatureAndroid"];

// The "Base64-encoded RSA public key" for your app, taken from the Google Play Console
// In the Classic Console: Your App -> Development Tools -> Services & APIs -> Licensing & in-app billing
// In the New Console: Your App -> Monetize -> Monetization Setup -> Licensing
$base64EncodedPublicKeyFromGoogle = "################";

// Convert the key into the normal public key format
// Just need to split the base64 key into 64 character long lines and add the usual prefix/suffix
$openSslFriendlyKey =
    "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" .
    chunk_split($base64EncodedPublicKeyFromGoogle, 64, "\n") .
    "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
// Convert the key to the openssl key ID that openssl_verify() expects
// I'm unsure if this step would be necessary on all platforms
$publicKeyId = openssl_get_publickey($openSslFriendlyKey);

// Use openssl_verify() to verify the $signature (which has to be base64 decoded!) against the $data using the public key we have
$result = openssl_verify(
    $data,
    base64_decode($signature),
    $publicKeyId,
    OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1
);

if ($result === 0) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid receipt");
}

if ($result !== 1) {
    throw new Exception(openssl_error_string());
}

// receipt data is valid. now let's grab the productId and purchaseToken
$decodedData = json_decode($data, true);
$purchasedProductId = decodedData["productId"];
$purchaseToken = decodedData["purchaseToken"];

// now we'll verify that the receipt is valid for our account
try {
    $googleClient = new \Google_Client();
    $googleClient->setScopes([
        \Google_Service_AndroidPublisher::ANDROIDPUBLISHER,
    ]);
    $googleClient->setApplicationName($appId);
    $googleClient->setAuthConfig($serviceAccountJson);
    $googleAndroidPublisher = new \Google_Service_AndroidPublisher(
        $googleClient
    );
    $purchase = $googleAndroidPublisher->purchases_products->get(
        $appId,
        $purchasedProductId,
        $purchaseToken
    );
} catch (Throwable $exception) {
    // this means the receipt data is unable to be validated by Google
    throw new Exception("Invalid receipt");
}
```

Comment: Hey Cory, long time no speak. Looks like I just had a double dollar sign at the start of that variable? Seemed like a simple typo. I updated my original answer to fix that.